# Evaluating $\int_0^{\infty}\frac1{x^9+1}~\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How can we evaluate this integral?
$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac1{x^9+1}~\mathrm{d}x$$

Comment: You must have *some idea*. If not, how did you get this question in the first place? The title on the top of the homework sheet might give you a clue.

Comment: Make the change of variables $y=x^9/(x^9+1)$, and then use the beta function and Euler reflection formula.

Answer (score 10):

Let me extend my comment and obtain the answer for a more general integral 
$$I(\gamma)=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{dx}{1+x^{\gamma}},\qquad \gamma>1.$$
The change of variables
$$y=\frac{1}{1+x^{\gamma}},\qquad x=\left(\frac{1-y}{y}\right)^{1/\gamma},\qquad dx=-\frac{1}{\gamma y^2}\left(\frac{1-y}{y}\right)^{1/\gamma-1}dy$$
transforms it into
\begin{align}
I(\gamma)&=\frac{1}{\gamma}\int_0^1 y^{-1/\gamma}\left(1-y\right)^{1/\gamma-1}dy=\\
&=\frac1\gamma B\left(1-\frac1\gamma,\frac1\gamma\right)=\\
&=\frac1\gamma\Gamma\left(1-\frac1\gamma\right)\Gamma\left(\frac1\gamma\right)=\\
&=\frac{\pi}{\gamma \sin\frac{\pi}{\gamma}},
\end{align}
where at the first step we use the [beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function), at the second its expression in terms of gamma functions, and at the third [Euler's reflection formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula).

Comment: Nice answer, definitely not worthy of a downvote. (+1)

Answer (score 4):

> *How can we evaluate this integral ?*

By letting $t=\dfrac1{x^9+1}$ , and recognizing the expression of the [beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) in the new integral,

then applying [Euler's reflection formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula) for the [$\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Properties) to that expression in order to finally

arrive at $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{n-1}}{x^m+1}dx=\frac\pi m\cdot\csc\bigg(n\cdot\frac\pi m\bigg)$, which for $n=1$ and $m=9$ becomes $\dfrac\pi{9\cdot\sin\dfrac\pi9}$

Answer (score 3):

Using contour integration, in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/176216), it is shown that
$$
\frac{\pi}{m}\csc\left(\pi\frac{n+1}{m}\right)=\int_0^\infty\frac{x^n}{1+x^m}\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
Plugging in $n=0$ and $m=9$ yields
$$
\int_0^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1+x^9}=\frac\pi9\csc\left(\frac\pi9\right)
$$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
\begin{align}
&\color{#00f}{\large\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dd x \over x^{9} + 1}}
=\int_{0}^{\infty}\pars{\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-\pars{x^{9} + 1}\xi}\,\dd\xi}\,\dd x
\\[3mm]&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-\xi}
\pars{\overbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-\xi x^{9}}\,\dd x}
^{\ds{\mbox{Set}\ t \equiv \xi x^{9}\ \imp\ x = \xi^{-1/9}t^{1/9}}}}\,\dd\xi
\\[3mm]&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-\xi}\pars{\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-t}\xi^{-1/9}\,
{1 \over 9}\,t^{-8/9}\,\dd t}\,\dd\xi
\\[3mm]&={1 \over 9}\pars{\int_{0}^{\infty}\xi^{-1/9}\expo{-\xi}\,\dd\xi}
\pars{\int_{0}^{\infty}t^{-8/9}\expo{-t}\,\dd t}
={1 \over 9}\,\Gamma\pars{8 \over 9}\Gamma\pars{1 \over 9}
\end{align}
where $\ds{\Gamma\pars{z}}$ is the [Gamma Function](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_253.htm).

> By using the
>   [Euler Reflection Formula](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_256.htm)
>   ${\bf\mbox{6.1.17}}$:
>   \begin{align}
> &\color{#00f}{\large\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dd x \over x^{9} + 1}}
> =\color{#00f}{\large{1 \over 9}\,\pi\,\csc\pars{\pi \over 9}}
> \end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Denote $a_k= \frac{(2k-1)\pi}9$ and integrate via partial fraction
\begin{align}
& \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+x^{9}} dx
=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1+x^{7}}{1+x^{9}}dx \\
=&\int_0^1 \sum_{k=1}^{4} \frac{\frac49\sin^2 a_k}{x^2-2x \cos a_k+1 }\ dx
=-\sum_{k=1}^{4} \frac{4\pi k}{81} \sin a_k\\
=& \ \frac d{dt}\bigg(\frac29\sum_{k=1}^{4} \cos a_k t\bigg)_{t=1}
=\frac d{dt}\bigg(\frac{\sin 2\pi t}{18\sin\frac{\pi t}9} \bigg)_{t=1}
=\frac{\pi}{9} \csc \frac{\pi}{9}
\end{align}

Comment: How did you get partial fractions for $(1+x^7)/(1+x^9)$ so quickly?

Comment: @BobDobbs - it is not easy. I had to work it out; I skipped the steps here.

Answer (score 0):

Quickest answer, without refering to an answer. Lets take the counter clockwise contour on $\Bbb C$ with rays $\theta=\frac{2\pi}{9}$ and $\theta=0$. Now, $w=e^{\frac{\pi i}{9}}$ is the only pole of $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^9+1}$ of order $1$ inside the contour. By residue throrem,
$$(-w^2+1)I=2\pi i\frac{1}{9w^8}.$$
Hence, $I=\int_0^\infty f(x)dx=\frac\pi 9\csc\frac\pi 9.$